# iOS (Swift): UICollectionView for a given UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass that is contained within a `UICollectionView` as follows:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet public var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as? MyCell else { fatalError("Unexpected indexPath") }
        return cell
    }

}
```

Is there any way to access the `collectionView` instance defined in `MyViewController` from within `MyCell`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just use delegate and @protocol.

Comment: @user3344236 Thank you -- so there is no built-in method or variable that gives this information from within `UICollectionViewCell`?

Comment: What is the reason for making a collection view cell as collection view data source? I think its really a bad idea.

Comment: @AkshaysinghYaduvanshi Yes this was a typo -- fixed now. I still want access to the `collectionView` instance from `MyCell`, however.

Comment: @Alex What is the reason for doing that? I am just asking to see if i can provide a better solution for doing the same.

Comment: @AkshaysinghYaduvanshi `MyCell` shows the data for an object and has a `UIButton` that changes a value of the data shown for this object. However, when this parameter is changed, it also changes the values for the other objects shown, thus the need to call `collectionView.reloadData()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    weak var outerCollectionView: UICollectionView!
 }
```

and set it in `cellForRowAt`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as? MyCell else { fatalError("Unexpected indexPath") }
    cell.outerCollectionView = collectionView
    return cell
}
```

//

Or you can try to cast the superView like this

```
let collectionView = self.superView as! UICollectionView
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think `MyCell` wants the `UICollectionViewDataSource` but rather `MyViewController` should have that.

Comment: you can try self.superView

Comment: Definitely make that a `weak` property, or you’re causing a retain cycle.

Comment: @ABeard89  does the answer below as an extension make sense?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I've turned these comments / answer into an extension for the `UICollectionViewCell` class

Comment: Without trying the extension, I don’t know if it will work or not since scroll views tend to have a content view which holds individual pieces. So my instinct is you’d have to traverse 2-3 views up the hierarchy.

Comment: If you absolutely need to do this, I think this answer is the better option, since Apple could change the view hierarchy on a whim. That being said, there isn’t a standard way to do this because it’s bad form. I would advise against this sort of thing and employ a delegate pattern instead—the cell shouldn’t need to reference the collection view.

Answer (score 1):

Following suggestions in the comments:

```
extension UICollectionViewCell {

    /// The collection view that presents this cell.
    weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
        return self.superview as! UICollectionView
    }
}
```

Comment: no need for as? if you're 100% crashes will guide you

Comment: @Sh_Khan Does this not crash with a fatal error though if somehow a `UICollectionViewCell` has not been placed within a `UICollectionView`? Do you recommend forcing the downcast using: `return self.superview as! UICollectionView`

Comment: a cellection cell can only be a subview for a UICollectionView no other options

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below

```
protocol MyCellDelegate {
    func reloadData()
}
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var delegate: MyCellDelegate!
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    //lets say this is your view controller and datasource
}

extension MyViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    //Methods are not implemeted here
    //But you can set the delegate of the cell in cellForRowAtIndex method which is your view controller
}

extension MyViewController: MyCellDelegate {
   func reloadData() {
        //Here you reload the collection view
   }
}
```